# Solr documents missing from some indexes

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

I have a collection in SolrCloud (v9.2) containing documents that look like:

```json
{
  "id": <uuid>           // unique doc ID
  "general_id": <uuid>   // shared ID, not unique per doc
  "thing": <string>      // what I want to query on
}
```

From the collection schema, the `name` field is configured like:

```json
// thing
{
  "name": "thing",
  "type": "string",
  "multiValued": false,
  "indexed": true,
  "required": false,
  "stored": false
}

// general_id
{
  "name": "general_id",
  "type": "uuid",
  "indexed": true,
  "stored": true,
  "useDocValuesAsStored": false,
  "uninvertible": false,
  "docValues": true,
  "multiValued": false,
  "required": true
}

// ... with copy field for "thing" but not for "general_id"

{
  "source": "thing",
  "dest": "_text_"
}
```

(`thing` still gets returned in docs even though `stored: false`; AFAIU this is because of something involving `string` type and `docValues`).

My goal is to use a filter query on `thing` like `thing:"Doo Dad"` and get the `general_id` values from matching documents.

When I do a query with `{..., "filter":["general_id":<some uuid>, "thing":"*"]}` (I use JSON API) to get all docs where a `thing` existed for a `general_id`, I can confirm that this particular `general_id` does have a `thing` that is a `Doo Dad`.

However, when I do `{..., "filter":["thing:\"Doo Dad\""]}`, the `general_id` *I know should be returned* is not in the results set. My understanding is that this must mean that the document did not get correctly added to the index for `thing`, but did get correctly added to the index for `general_id`.

(Non-exhaustive things I've tried so far)

1. I've tried this both as a filter query and as a regular query.
2. I've tried deleting all docs for the target `general_id` and reindexing them.
3. I've tried disabling results cache.
4. I've set the `limit` parameter extremely high (kinda a hail mary)

What I expect is that when I do a filter query for an exact match, *all* docs that match be included in the result set.

Update: I have found that I can eventually get results for a given `general_id` to work as expected if I delete and reindex its documents enough times - sometimes more than 3x. I would read this as support for the issue being something to do with indexing. (Obviously not a tenable solution, though.)

Comment: There isn't anything like a "phrase match" for a `string` field - a `string` field will always have to be matched exactly - casing and all. What is the content you've actually indexing into `thing`? Does issuing a regular select query with `fq` work instead?

Comment: What I mean there is just ensuring that the whole phrase gets submitted correctly: if I do `thing:Doo Dad` instead of `thing:"Doo Dad"`, the standard query parser will treat it as `thing:Doo` and `_text_:Dad`, so quoting the contents becomes necessary. (I've confirmed this behavior with `?debug=true` output)

Comment: As far as the contents go, if I have indexed multiple documents with different `general_id` but the same `thing` ("Doo Dad", in this case), _some_ of the docs will be returned on filter query for `thing:"Doo Dad"` later. The mystery is why there are docs that I know have the same content - I create and index them in exactly the same way - but are not included in the result set.

Comment: Removed "phrase match" language per your comment; was probably more confusing than clarifying.